# keyframe animation fires on class removal on IE (10, 11,12, 13)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, css-animations

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/jsms8p1k/15/)

[Reproduction with vanilla Javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/jsms8p1k/16/)

I'm creating a CSS animation by using this:

```
.slides.future.active {
  -webkit-animation-name: sectionIn;
  animation-name: sectionIn;
}
@keyframes sectionIn {
  ....
}{

.animated {
    transition: all 800ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms ease;

    -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
    animation-duration: 800ms;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;

    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    timing-function: ease;
}
.slides.future{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0 );
}
```

Having the following HTML:

```
<div id="demo2" class="slides animated future active">
   Demo
</div>
<div class="slides animated future">Demo 2</div>
```

Now, when I remove the class `future` from the element, the animation gets fired again.

This only happends in IE. (10, 11, 12, 13) Working well in Firefox, Chrome, Safari...

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/jsms8p1k/15/)

[Reproduction with vanilla Javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/jsms8p1k/16/)

Comment: FWIW Internet Explorer only goes up to version 11.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly it depends on how you consider Edge versions. [Browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com) calls it 12 and 13.

Comment: Edge is a different browser altogether. It runs on something called "EdgeHTML" which first appeared in IE11 and is subsequently now on version 14, but Microsoft Edge as a browser is currently on version 20-something.

Comment: @Pimmol has a solution but to find the best solution we need more informations. What are you trying to achieve exactly ? I believe the `.slide` class is just style, the `animated ` class if or animation but I don't quite get the `future` class. Could you give us a bit more context? Also in your demos you have two `demo2` ids which is not correct.

Comment: The problem is not on what I'm trying to do, but more about trying to understand how IE deals with animations and why it does it differently than other browsers. 
I could achieve a similar result in other way, but I'm using this one because I want an animation to take place whenever I dynamically add an element with the class `active` on it. I do not want to add the class `active` dynamically to get the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to change the CSS selector.

Instead of `.animated` use `.future.animated` and apply the animation on that selector.

```
.future.animated {
   transition: all 800ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms ease;

  -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
  animation-duration: 800ms;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;

  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  timing-function: ease;
}
```

That way only the element with both classes gets animated. So removing the class `future` from the element prevents it from animating again.

https://jsfiddle.net/jsms8p1k/17/

Comment: Working as expected. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Strangely (not very strange for IE) you need to also tell the browser what to do when `.slides` and `.active` are there but not `.future`. If you don't then for that split second it goes back to where it was until it gets the instruction to revert back again. So you need to add:

```
.slides.active:not(.future){
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0 );
}
```

**Note:** Tested in IE 11 only.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsms8p1k/19/)**

Comment: This implies having to duplicate the transform properties from the animation styles, and also, doing it for as many classes with animations I want to add. (slides.past, slides.future...) This is the main reason I chose the other answer. With his approach I can just do `.future.animated, .past.animated` and I do not have to duplicate properties.